# 'git log --skip' returning empty inside github action

Tags: git, github-actions

I have 1 job running inside my workflow inside a github action. One of the steps is:

```
 - name: Catch commit changes \\
   run: |
     COMMITLOG=$(git log -n 1 --skip 1 --pretty="format:%H")
     git diff --name-only $COMMITLOG..HEAD > commit_log_raw.txt
```

The  `git log` is returning empty and I isolated the problem being when I add the `--skip` argument. I've tried the solutions on [this issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/1049) and none worked.

Comment: I think GitHub Actions does a shallow clone or something by default. Anyway, separate from that, is this a verbose way of doing `git show --name-only > commit_log_raw.txt`?

Comment: [_"Only a single commit is fetched by default..."_](https://github.com/actions/checkout#readme)

Comment: @jonrsharpe setting the ```fetch-depth: 0``` inside the ```actions/checkout@v4``` step worked. Thanks, I shoud've read the action documentation more carefully

Comment: (If you only need one more commit, you should set it to 2 to avoid waste.)